# How to concatenate strings in Icarus Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, string-concatenation, iverilog

I have a SV printing task that concatenates some input strings and prints a message. This code works on Cadence's tools, but when I tried porting to `iverilog`, I get compile errors.

```
    task Error (
        input string msg,
        input string name = ""
    );
        begin
            $timeformat(-9, 2, " ns", 12);
            name = (name.len() > 0) ? {_ModuleName(name), ": "} : "";
            $display("  Error: at %0t: %0s%0s", $time, name, msg);
        end
    endtask
```

And the error message:
`error: Data types string and bool of ternary do not match.`

I guess this may be unsupported by tools, but I could not find an exact reference on this. I suspect strings concatenation may not work as I expect, but again - hard to find info on concatenation supported by `iverilog`.

```
# iverilog -v
Icarus Verilog version 12.0 (stable) (s20221226-238-g9e4c4d546)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is legal for IEEE Std 1800 (SystemVerilog).  Many simulators support the syntax, but your version of `iverilog` does not (and neither does the version I have).  If your version is new, then this syntax is just not supported yet.

You can use an `if/else` instead of a ternary operator.  Obviously, this code is more verbose, but it works if you are stuck with `iverilog`:

```
module tb;
task Error (
        input string msg,
        input string name = ""
    );
        begin
            $timeformat(-9, 2, " ns", 12);
            if (name.len() > 0) begin
                $display("  Error: at %0t: %0s:%0s", $time, name, msg);
            end else begin
                $display("  Error: at %0t: %0s", $time, msg);
            end
        end
endtask

initial begin
    #3 Error("aaa", "bbb");
    #3 Error("ccc");
end
endmodule
```

I have not found a list of SystemVerilog features supported by `iverilog`.  You find out what's supported mostly by trial and error.  Before I wrote the code above, I tried constructing a string using `$sformatf`, but the `iverilog` version I have gave me an error.